# PayPal Adaptive Payments Error 540031

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am trying to setup an adaptive payments example in PHP, but am being returned error 540031. PayPal shows that this is "You do not have permission to get these preapproval details."

First off.... I don't know what that means. Preapproval? For what. Second..... it is not documented on how to fix this error.

I have set my API info correctly and everything.

My code can be found here: http://pastie.org/private/6age2v0qfunsueqdxk03ba

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using the code sample I did and was getting the same.

Ended up finding this - https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-sdk-index#adaptivepaymentsnew

This is a more comprehensive library of sample code and seems to work better